# is it possible to access Hololens camera from Game mode in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/Windows.WebCam.PhotoCapture.html) to take a picture using the Hololens 2 camera and show it using a billboard (`Quad` object). When I try to run that code, even using Holographic Emulation and playing the scene in a connected Hololens 2, I get an error because the script cannot access the camera (`Failed to initialize IMediaCapture (hr = 0xC00DABE0)`). Thing that doesn't happen if I build the app and deploy it in the HoloLens 2.

My question is: is there a way to grant access to Unity to this camera, so when I hit Play and go into Game Mode (with Holographic Emulation enabled and the Hololens 2 connected), the script can access the camera?

Again, the script works if I effectively deploy it in the Hololens 2, but having to build the project in Unity and later in VS for every small test takes too long. I'm using **Unity 2019.4.26f** and **VS 2019**.

Code in case the link doesn't work:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam;

public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate(PhotoCapture captureObject) {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        // Copy the raw image data into our target texture
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

        // Create a gameobject that we can apply our texture to
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Renderer quadRenderer = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
        quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));

        quad.transform.parent = this.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

        quadRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);

        // Deactivate our camera
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        // Shutdown our photo capture resource
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommend to refer [Mixed reality capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/mixed-reality-capture-directx#render-from-the-pv-camera-opt-in) to get video stream to render on a texture or refer [Research Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/research-mode) to get in-depth camera/sensor data.

Please also double-check the asset directory is correct in this line:
`quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture"));`

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks for your answer. I'll check those links. As per the last part of your answer, "Until/Texture" is a default shader of Unity, AFAIK that's how you access the default shaders and materials in unity.

Comment: Please use a Mixed Reality Standard shader, and the directory should be "Mixed Reality Toolkit/Standard" as it is recommended on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/rendering/mrtk-standard-shader?view=mrtkunity-2022-05

Comment: Hi Seth DU, I'll check that. Regarding this question, do you know anything about accessing the camera from the Game mode in the editor? This might solve the problem I describe in my other question (a blank Quad on my deployed app), but not the one described here.

Comment: It is not supported. The runtime environment for Unity Editor is local machine instead of HoloLens. I am using a laptop for testing, so WebCamTexture.devices only output one web camera. As a workaround, you may add UI components for the web cam texture for adjustment and store configuration data for later use.